# Class Variables of my Fragment class are null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to write a test case for one of my fragment class.
For this, I add the fragment to my activity dynamically using:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

now if I try to do this:

```
fragment.getmAdapter() // returns null
```

I am always getting this as null, although mAdapter was initialized during the onCreateView method of fragment class.

I also tried to call `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
after fragmentTransaction.commit();
but now I get error that`fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
must be called from Main thread.

`

Comment: are you calling `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` from a non-UI thread

Comment: yes. This is my test class. I need to write test case for async task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter was null because the transactions were not yet completed i.e. they were pending to be executed at some later stage. And since robotium tests are not run over UI thread, executePendingTransactions() was not directly possible.

I solved it by making a call to execute pending transaction on UI thread i.e.

```
getactivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
});
```